# Question about right derived functors and duality

Tags: category-theory, functors, derived-functors, derived-categories

UPDATE after some thinking (and without comments or answers) I want to ask the following:

Say that I have a morphism $f:X\to Y$ of schemes and a induced morphism $f_*\colon \mathcal{S}(X)\to \mathcal{S}(Y)$. Let $A,B\in \mathcal{S}(X)$. Since $Rf_*$ is a functor from the derived category of $\mathcal{S}(X)$ to the derived category of $\mathcal{S}(Y)$ there is an induced morphism

$Rf_*(\textbf{Hom}(A,B))\to \textbf{Hom}(Rf_*A,Rf_*B)$.
Here $\textbf{Hom}$ is the set of Homomorphisms in the derived category, we also have $H^0\textbf{RHom}=\textbf{Hom}$.

Now if we let $B=f^!A'$ for some $A'$ in the derived category of  $\mathcal{S}(Y)$ the Grothendieck trace map induces a morphism
$$\textbf{Hom}(Rf_*A,Rf_*f^!A')\to \textbf{Hom}(Rf_*A,A')$$

Is this composition an isomorphism?

I.e., is $$Rf_*(\textbf{Hom}(A,f^!A'))\to \textbf{Hom}(Rf_*A,A')$$
an isomorphism?

By Grothendieck duality
$$Rf_*\textbf{RHom}(A,f^!A')\to \textbf{RHom}(Rf_*A,A')$$
is an isomorphism but if we apply $H^0$ to this we get

$$H^0Rf_*\textbf{RHom}(A,f^!A')\to \textbf{Hom}(Rf_*A,A')$$

Which seems pretty far from what I wanted unless if $f_*$ is exact.

Thank you for any input!